# Is there a better way to run oracle database with docker in a development environment?

Tags: docker, oracle11g

I need an oracle database instance in my dev environment and I found [oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g](https://hub.docker.com/r/oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g/) in Docker Hub.

My dataset is a big one. It would be good to keep the database file outside the container for future use.

I moved all necessary folders from container to host.

```
/media/db/oracle
├── admin
│   └── XE
│       ├── adump
│       └── dpdump
├── diag
│   ├── rdbms
│   └── tnslsnr
├── fast_recovery_area
│   └── XE
└── oradata
    └── XE
        ├── control.dbf
        ├── sysaux.dbf
        ├── system.dbf
        ├── temp.dbf
        ├── undotbs1.dbf
        └── users.dbf
```

And started the container like this:

```sh
sudo docker run -d --name oracle \
 -p 49161:1521 -p 8080:8080 \
 -v /media/db/oracle/admin:/u01/app/oracle/admin \
 -v /media/db/oracle/diag:/u01/app/oracle/diag \
 -v /media/db/oracle/fast_recovery_area:/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area \
 -v /media/db/oracle/oradata:/u01/app/oracle/oradata \
 oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g \
/
```

It works.

My question is: **Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: I don't know if you found an answer to this question, but I'm also interested. I had to start the image and save off the `/u01` directory to my host but wasn't sure what was important and what wasn't, so I saved the same directories you indicated and it seemed to work.

Comment: Anyway, it has been working for the last 9 months.